# initializing thread to new thread c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, operators, overloading

I have a not initializated thread "thr", and i wanna initalize it to new thread

```
thr=std::thread(&Engine::thread);
```

But i get error C2672: "std::invoke". I tried to replace &Engine::thread with this->thread, but gets another error C3867: "Engine::thread".
So how i can initialize thr to new thread?
thr was created below, `std::thread thr;`
And Engine::thread looks like this

```
inline void Engine::thread()
    {

    }
```

Sorry for my bad english, help me please

Comment: Please post complete error messages and a [mcve]

Comment: Oh, thanks for marking, i solved this by adding parametr to calling thr=std::thread(&Engine::render,Engine());